# Accessing client's custom performance counters

Tags: windows, sccm, sccm-2012, system-center, sccm-2012-r2

I would like to access client's custom performance counters in SCCM, is there any built-in functionality that would let me do that, if not, are there other some ways?

Comment: This sounds more like a SCOM thing to me rather than SCCM.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Powershell and WMI to look around:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\ccm -class sms_client
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\ccm -list
```

[It's fairly versatile.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2014/09/05/wmi-powershell-and-the-configuration-manager-client.aspx)